# I'm no longer able to unlock bitlocker locked drive on my Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, encryption

I have a dual booted machine, Windows 11 + Ubuntu 22.04.

I have a 3rd partition which is encrypted using Bitlocker from windows.

Earlier I was able to unlock my Bitlocker encrypted drive on Ubuntu just by clicking on it and entering the password, just how it's mentioned [here](https://itsfoss.com/mount-encrypted-windows-partition-linux/).

But now it shows following error

```
Error unlocking /dev/nvme0n1p5: The function 'bd_crypto_bitlk_open' called, but not implemented!
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Not sure if I have removed any package which is causing this issue.

Please help. Thanks in advance.